# what to choose for latin 1 character set when not available

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I've been given instructions to create a mysql database that uses latin1_bin for the collation (I'm using php admin). That worked fine but when I tried to import a data file, the tutorial I'm following also said to set the character set to latin1_bin. However in php myadmin (that's installed with MAMP) there is no option for latin1 when importing a file. These are the options [image] Which one should I choose for a latin1_bin database?

Comment: `_bin`?! What kind of database is it?

Comment: just following along with the lynda.com sql tutorial, uses php also

Comment: if a tutorial recommends you using `_bin` and `latin-1` - I would throw it to the rubbish bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what `ISO 8859-1` represents in your list